# How to change StatusBar in swiftUI?

Tags: ios, swift, statusbar, swiftui

Where is the correct place to write the code for Status Bar, and How can to change the Status Bar light or dark in SwiftUI?

Comment: Well, what do you mean? Light and dark mode? Isn't that part of the OS and why you want to use SwiftUI? You didn't tag this iOS but it should be because a status bar doesn't really exist elsewhere - so are you talk the equivalent of `UIKit`'s `preferredStatusBarStyle`? You're pretty light on details.

Comment: @dfd if your app always has a dark background, you will need to change the status bar color for light mode somehow.

Comment: @Hexagons, I agree - in fact, most of my `UIKit` apps (a) have a dark background, (b) I have a 3-4 step process to make everything light, and (c) do *not* support light/dark mode in iOS 13. My comment was asking for more *specifics* from the OP - it's really a candidate for voting to close (I haven't though).